# Error in astype float32 vs float64 for integer

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, floating-point

I'm sure this is due to a lapse in my understanding in how casting between different precision of float works, but can someone explain why the value is getting cast as 3 less than its true value in 32 vs 64 bit representation?

```
>>> a = np.array([83734315])
>>> a.astype('f')
array([ 83734312.], dtype=float32)
>>> a.astype('float64')
array([ 83734315.])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [32-bit float](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format) can exactly represent about 7 decimal digits of mantissa. Your number requires more, and therefore cannot be represented exactly.

The mechanics of what happens are as follows:

A 32-bit float has a 24-bit mantissa. Your number requires 27 bits to be represented exactly, so the last three bits are getting truncated (set to zero). The three lowest bits of your number are `011`<sub>2</sub>; these are getting set to `000`<sub>2</sub>. Observe that `011`<sub>2</sub> is `3`<sub>10</sub>.

Answer (score 3):

A `float32` only has 24 bits of significand precision, which is roughly seven digits (log10(2**24) = 7.22). You're expecting it to store an 8-digit number exactly, which in general is impossible.